# AttributeError: int object has no attribute 'execute'

Tags: python, mysql, tkinter, int, execute

```
def dodaj_student(self):
    self.db_conn.execute("INSERT INTO Students (FName, LName, Telefon, Wiek, PName)" +
                                               "VALUES ('" +
                                               self.imie_entry_value.get() + "', '" +
                                               self.nazwisko_entry_value.get() + "', '" +
                                               self.telefon_entry_value.get() + "', '" +
                                               self.wiek_entry_value.get() + "', '" +
                                              self.imierodzica_entry_value.get() + "')")
```

The function is connected to the button. While clicking, an `error` is occurring.
It shows error:

```
AttributeError: int object has no attribute execute
```

Comment: Can you show where you set `db_conn`?

Comment: Your `self.db_conn` is an int.  Probably not what you wanted.

Comment: You need to show more code - the db_conn is an int, but probably needs to be  some form of database connection. Show how you set it.